# Chart.js 3.5.1 Attribute question about zeroLineColor

Tags: chart.js

I hope someone can help!  I am using chart.js 3.5.1 and have a specific chart in mind.  However, a lot of the documentation online is for seemingly an old version of chart.js.  I need a simple line chart with data on the y axis both above and below zero.  To emphasis this I would like a darker axis line on the 0, all online material suggests that I can use zeroLineColor.  However, the new version of chart.js does not seem to support this.  All the online material is using xAxis:[] and yAxis:[], while mine is using simply x:{} and y:{} which makes me think that the zeroLinecolor attribute has been deprecated, if so can what I require be implemented another way?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the scriptable options for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        grid: {
          color: (ctx) => (ctx.index === 0 ? 'black' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Haha thanks mate - just found that myself :D it was driving me round the bend trying to get that to work! Very much appreciate your more elegant code in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the answer!  if it of use to anyone, then you need to add a scriptable component to grid:

```
          grid: {
            color: context => context.tick.value == 0 ? '#555555' : '#CCCCCC'
          }
```

Comment: Value of the zeroline tick wont always be 0, it would be better to use the index of the line